# Alter command is failing due to unique key constraints of another existing field in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, alter-table

So I am running a migration command `ALTER TABLE wallet_transactions ADD COLUMN entity_type varchar(100) NULL,  ADD COLUMN entity_value varchar(100) NULL;` on a table which has more than 34 million rows, it is giving me an error that `Duplicate entry '68C9F86597C44539B193FC8E71625153' for key 'transaction_id`.

The weird thing here is that transaction_id is a field that already exists in the table and has a unique key constraint so why is my migration failing because of this field?

I tried migrating through django migrations or through raw sql also but both times it got failed.  I tried updating that particular transaction_id thinking that there might be an issue with this specific row but migration again failed citing a different transaction_id.

I want to understand why MYSQL behaves like this and the possible solution.

MYSQL Version - 5.7.38

Comment: Do you actually have duplicate entries in the transaction_id column?

Comment: *The weird thing here is that transaction_id is a field that already exists in the table and has a unique key constraint so why is my migration failing because of this field?* Does this UNIQUE constraint/index is present in the table structure? check `SHOW CREATE TABLE wallet_transactions;`.

Comment: Are the values truly duplicated? Did you change the default character set / collation on database or table level since you created this table and thus mysql may be converting the existing column to a different character set / collation causing the error message?

Comment: @NickW  No I do not have duplicate entries in transaction_id, it has a unique field constraint.

Comment: @Akina I checked the create table query and it has a unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query to check how much duplicate values are present in the table:

```
SELECT transaction_id, COUNT(transaction_id) FROM wallet_transactions 
GROUP BY transaction_id
HAVING COUNT(transaction_id) > 1;
```

If you get any transaction id from this query, you have to change the ids one by one.

*** Inform us if you don't get any value from this query.

Comment: I tried the above query the very first time I got duplicate key error, there is no duplicate transaction_id in the table

Comment: Run this below given query. This will create a new table called "wallet_transactions_test". 


**CREATE TABLE `wallet_transactions_test` SELECT * FROM `wallet_transactions`; **

Next Update the id column

UPDATE wallet_transactions_test  SET transaction_id=TRIM(transaction_id);

Now alter your table 

ALTER TABLE wallet_transactions_test  
  CHARSET = utf8mb4,
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci;

 ALTER TABLE wallet_transactions_test
  CHANGE `transaction_id` `transaction_id` INT NOT NULL,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`transaction_id`);

Try to do this.